# DataChannelObserver - adapter needed and unhandled websocket message Err(Protocol(ResetWithoutClosingHandshake)) error

Tags: windows, next.js, livekit

I'm trying to run a livekit application on windows but I am met with these errors:

```
[2023-09-28T19:04:38Z WARN  libwebrtc] (sctp_data_channel.cc:369): DataChannelObserver - adapter needed
[2023-09-28T19:04:38Z WARN  libwebrtc] (sctp_data_channel.cc:369): DataChannelObserver - adapter needed
[2023-09-28T19:04:38Z INFO  livekit::rtc_engine] received session close: server request to leave, DuplicateIdentity
[2023-09-28T19:04:38Z ERROR livekit_api::signal_client::signal_stream] unhandled websocket message Err(Protocol(ResetWithoutClosingHandshake))
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

I've tried disabling firewalls but I'm very lost at this point.